# How to return numberOfRowsInSection to Tableview with two conditions in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview

I am adding JSON to model like below code

```
var userModel : ProfileModel? 

 if httpResponse!.statusCode == 200 {
                do {
                    let jsonObject  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableLeaves) as! [String :AnyObject]
                    self.userModel = ProfileModel.init(fromDictionary: jsonObject)

                    if (self.userModel?.userId) != nil {

                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.updateUserDetails()
                            self.addressTableview.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                } catch { print(error.localizedDescription) }
            }
```

**now i need to add the model value in one row and for remaining rows i need to show `addressArray` values.. how to do that in table view `numberOfRowsInSection` and in `cellForRowAt indexPath`**

so i have tried below code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if userModel?.userAddresses != nil{
        return userModel?.userAddresses.count ?? 0

    }
    else{
        return addressArray.count
    }
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: AddresCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "AddresCell") as! AddresCell

    let addr = userModel?.userAddresses![indexPath.row]

    if addr?.addressId != nil{
                  let street = addr?.streetName
                  let colony = addr?.colony
                  let city   = addr?.city
                   let pincode = addr?.pincode
                    cell.address.text = street! + "," + colony! + "," + city! + "," + pincode!
                    KeychainWrapper.standard.set(cell.address.text ?? "", forKey: "ADDRESS")
    }

    else{
            cell.address.text = addressArray[indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
    }
```

first time first row address is coming to row from model..here if i add new address then the first row address and added address has to come but... here for each time with new address the model value also pairing (new and model value))

**i need only first time model value to row all the time only added new address**
here `addressArray` coming from another view controller

please help me to solve this issue

Comment: On which line do you get the error?

Comment: `cell.address.text = addressArray[indexPath.row]` this line in else

Comment: `addressArray[indexPath.row]` cannot work. The array must match the array which returns the number of items in `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: @vadian i have taken your suggestion and edited post.. here for new address both new and model value coming, why?.. where i am wrong, could you suggest me please

Comment: I don't know where the different arrays come from. My suggestion is to consolidate your data source array. And use less optionals, `userModel?.userAddresses.count ?? 0` is horrible. Declare the data source array as non-optional **array**.